# Creating circular entities using entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Having the following entities:

```
public class Application{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("applicationId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles {get; set;}
}

public class Role{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int applicationId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Permissions> Permissions {get; set;}
}

public class Permission{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int RoleId {get; set;}

    public int applicationId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("applicationId")]
    public virtual Application application {get; set;}
}
```

As you can see, the `Permission` entity also refers back to the Application entity so that I currently have circular references.

Is there any way to Create a full dataset including all references respectively how can I save that entites using Entity Framework?

In my controller I get one Application Object as Parameter including all childs (excluded the applicationId of the Permission entity).

Comment: Can a Permission be associated with an different Application from its Role?  If not, why not just have a Navigation property to Role.  So you can call Permission.Role.Application if you need to traverse from a Permission to an Applciation?

Comment: Yes, the permission can be associated to the application because of some administration reasons. In some cases roles are missing and so the "permission" needs to know to which application it belongs. But more interesting is how I can solve that using the entity framework? Is there any clever clue?

Comment: The model you have should work.  If you select all the Applications then when EF loads a Permission if the change tracker already has an Application with the correct applicationId it will set the Navigation Property to the already-loaded entity.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the mentioned issue to change the table structure. I guess it's never that good to have circular dependencies. So I changed it from:

```
Application --> Role --> RolePermission --> Permission --> Application ...
```

to

```
Application --> Permission --> RolePermission --> Role
```

The reason for having permission directly referenced to application is, that the permissions are hard coded for each controller-method (like [Can("read-entity")]. The role itself is variable.